# Delphi - Compare and Mark String Differences

Tags: delphi, string-comparison

What I need to do is compare two strings and mark the differences with begining/ending marks for changes.  Example:

```
this is string number one.
```

```
this string is string number two.
```

output would be

```
this [is|string is] string number [one|two].
```

I've been trying to figure this out for some time now.  And I found something I blieved would help me do this, but I am unable to make this happen.
 http://www.angusj.com/delphi/textdiff.html

I have it about 80% working here, but I've got no idea how to get it to do exactly what I want it to do.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, Diff, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Button1: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Diff: TDiff;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;
  s1,s2:string;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
  lastKind: TChangeKind;

  procedure AddCharToStr(var s: string; c: char; kind, lastkind: TChangeKind);
  begin
    if (kind  lastkind) AND (lastkind = ckNone) and (kind  ckNone) then s:=s+'[';
    if (kind  lastkind) AND (lastkind  ckNone) and (kind = ckNone) then s:=s+']';
    case kind of         
      ckNone: s := s  + c;
      ckAdd: s := s + c;         
      ckDelete: s := s  + c;
      ckModify: s := s + '|' + c;
    end;
  end;

begin
  Diff.Execute(pchar(edit1.text), pchar(edit2.text), length(edit1.text), length(edit2.text));

  //now, display the diffs ...
  lastKind := ckNone;
  s1 := ''; s2 := '';
  form2.caption:= inttostr(diff.Count);
  for i := 0 to Diff.count-1 do
  begin

    with Diff.Compares[i] do
    begin
      //show changes to first string (with spaces for adds to align with second string)
      if Kind = ckAdd then 
      begin 
        AddCharToStr(s1,' ',Kind, lastKind); 
      end
      else 
      AddCharToStr(s1,chr1,Kind,lastKind);
      if Kind = ckDelete then 
      begin 
        AddCharToStr(s2,' ',Kind, lastKind)
      end
      else AddCharToStr(s2,chr2,Kind,lastKind);

      lastKind := Kind;
    end;
  end;
    memo1.Lines.Add(s1);
    memo1.Lines.Add(s2);
end;

end.
```

I took the basicdemo1 from angusj.com and modified it to get this far.

Comment: Did you check Torry to see if there's a component that does what you want? (http://www.torry.net/)

Comment: I looked but didn't see anything, not sure I know what to search for. I looked again and found strDiff it might work.  Thanks

Comment: I checked again, didn't find anything that I could make work.

Comment: You could also try the embarcadero forums - after all they wrote Delphi: https://newsgroups.embarcadero.com/index.jspa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve the problem you describe, you'd essentially have to do something like what is done in [biological sequence alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_alignment) of DNA or protein data. If you only have two strings (or one constant reference string), it can approached by [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming)-based pairwise alignment algorithms such as the [Needleman Wunsch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needleman%E2%80%93Wunsch_algorithm)* and related algorithms. (Multiple sequence alignment gets much more complicated.)

[* Edit: link should be: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needleman–Wunsch_algorithm ]

**Edit 2:**

Since you seem to be interested in comparing at the level of words rather than characters, you could (1) split the input strings into arrays of strings, where each array element represents a word and then (2) carry out the alignment at the level of these words. This has the benefit of the search space for the alignment becoming smaller and thus you'd expect it to be faster overall. I have adapted and 'Delphified' the pseudo-code example from the wikipedia-article accordingly:

```
program AlignWords;
```

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

function MaxChoice (C1, C2, C3: integer): integer;
begin
  Result:= C1;
  if C2 > Result then Result:= C2;
  if C3 > Result then Result:= C3;
end;

function WordSim (const S1, S2: String): integer; overload;
//Case-sensitive!
var i, l1, l2, minL: integer;
begin
  l1:= length(S1);
  l2:= length(S2);
  Result:= l1-l2;
  if Result > 0 then Result:= -Result;
  if (S1='') or (S2='') then exit;
  minL:= l1;
  if l2 < l1 then minL:= l2;
  for i := 1 to minL do if S1[i]<>S2[i] then dec(Result);
end;

procedure AlignWordsNW (const A, B: Array of String; GapChar: Char; const Delimiter: ShortString; GapPenalty: integer; out AlignmentA, AlignmentB: string);
// Needleman-Wunsch alignment
// GapPenalty should be a negative value!
var
  F: array of array of integer;
  i, j,
  Choice1, Choice2, Choice3,
  Score, ScoreDiag, ScoreUp, ScoreLeft :integer;
  function GapChars (const S: String): String;
  var i: integer;
  begin
    assert (length(S)>0);
    Result:='';
    for i := 0 to length(S) - 1 do Result:=Result + GapChar;
  end;
begin
  SetLength (F, length(A)+1, length(B)+1);
  for i := 0 to length(A) do F[i,0]:= GapPenalty*i;
  for j := 0 to length(B) do F[0,j]:= GapPenalty*j;
  for i:=1 to length(A) do begin
    for j:= 1 to length(B) do begin
      Choice1:= F[i-1,j-1] + WordSim(A[i-1], B[j-1]);
      Choice2:= F[i-1, j] + GapPenalty;
      Choice3:= F[i, j-1] + GapPenalty;
      F[i,j]:= maxChoice (Choice1, Choice2, Choice3);
    end;
  end;
  AlignmentA:= '';
  AlignmentB:= '';
  i:= length(A);
  j:= length(B);
  while (i > 0) and (j > 0) do begin
    Score := F[i,j];
    ScoreDiag:= F[i-1,j-1];
    ScoreUp:= F[i,j-1];
    ScoreLeft:= F[i-1,j];
    if Score = ScoreDiag + WordSim(A[i-1], B[j-1]) then begin
      AlignmentA:= A[i-1] + Delimiter + AlignmentA;
      AlignmentB:= B[j-1] + Delimiter + AlignmentB;
      dec (i);
      dec (j);
    end else if Score = ScoreLeft + GapPenalty then begin
      AlignmentA:= A[i-1] + Delimiter + AlignmentA;
      AlignmentB:= GapChars (A[i-1]) + Delimiter + AlignmentB;
      dec(i);
    end else begin
      assert (Score = ScoreUp + GapPenalty);
      AlignmentA:= GapChars(B[j-1]) + Delimiter + AlignmentA;
      AlignmentB:= B[j-1] + Delimiter + AlignmentB;
      dec (j);
    end;
  end;
  while (i > 0) do begin
    AlignmentA:= A[i-1] + Delimiter + AlignmentA;
    AlignmentB:= GapChars(A[i-1]) + Delimiter + AlignmentB;
    dec(i);
  end;
  while (j > 0) do begin
    AlignmentA:= GapChars(B[j-1]) + Delimiter + AlignmentA;
    AlignmentB:= B[j-1] + Delimiter + AlignmentB;
    dec(j);
  end;
end;

Type
  TStringArray = Array Of String;

Var
  as1, as2: TStringArray;
  s1, s2: string;

BEGIN
    as1:= TStringArray.create ('this','is','string','number','one.');
    as2:= TStringArray.Create ('this','string','is','string','number','two.');

```
AlignWordsNW (as1, as2, '-',' ',-1, s1,s2);
writeln (s1);
writeln (s2);
```

END.

The output on this example is

```
this ------ is string number ---- one. 
this string is string number two. ----
```

It's not perfect, but you get the idea. From this sort of output, you should be able to do what you want. Note that you might want to tweak the `GapPenalty` and the Similarity Scoring Function `WordSim` to fit your needs.

Comment: I found an example of this at http://www.mx-dev.net/delphi/sources/source-6-alignement-de-sequences-d-adn.zip (requires login, doesn't check your email address to be valid) but I don't understand the algorithm/code enough to modify it. :( (not to mention comments are in French or Spanish)

Comment: If you are not concerned with finding optimal solutions, and/or want to present several alternatives, you could simply evaluate all possible char x char combinations of the two source strings [graphically, this corresponds to a dot-plot: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_plot_(bioinformatics) ]. Here, (graphically) the diagonals correspond to the matching substrings and you can map the start and stop positions of these.

Comment: Sorry, don't seem to be able to access the code in your link. But have a look at the  Needleman–Wunsch wikipedia article. It has pseudo-code and links to functioning code in other languages. (Don't worry, for strings encoding e.g. English, you won't have to bother with complicated score matrices.)

Answer (score 1):

There is an [Object Pascal Diff Engine](http://flocke.vssd.de/prog/code/pascal/pasdiff/0.4/Diff.pas.html) available which might be of assistance. You might want to break each "word" into a separate line for the comparison, or modify the algorithm to compare on a word by word basis.

Comment: I will look into this again, when I tried to work with it's demo on Torry it crashed with divide by zero errors, so I didn't go any further.